# How to find S3 connected to a cloudfront URL

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

The client has a site running on PHP deployed over AWS infrastructure. I have access to AWS console of a client.

There are some images in his site that is loading from cloudfront (which I understand is mapped to an S3 bucket). I need to update these images, but I do not know which S3 bucket they are in, since client has a lot of S3 buckets configured. How do I figure this one from the console?

Answer (score 1):

First, you will need to find the CloudFront distribution that is serving the content. Find the distribution with the same `cloudfront.net` URL that you're using to access the images.

Then, look at the **behaviors** and **origins** of the distribution to determine *when* it is going to each origin, and *which* origin is serving the path. This will then tell you which Amazon S3 bucket is being used.

Answer (score 0):

also to add on John's answer; after you have changed the image in origin S3 bucket; you will have to invalidate the cache for those images in CloudFront .. otherwise even though origin has changed u will keep seeing old images